# Is there any other way to check multiple values are present in array of object?

Tags: javascript

I have the below array of objects and I want to check if two different users are present in this array .if present i have to run some logic

```js
let result = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

var newArr = [];

var hasMatch = result.filter(function(val) {
  if (val.name == "FGH"){
    newArr.push(val)
  } else if (val.name == "ABC") {
    newArr.push(val)
  }
});
console.log(newArr)

if (newArr.length == 2) {
  //do logic
}
```

It's working as expected but I'm looking for a different approach for this. could someone advise?

Comment: What aspect(s) of this approach are you trying to remedy?

Comment: `(result.filter(r => r.name === "FGH").length > 0 && result.filter(r => r.name === "ABC").length > 0)`

Comment: do you want only to check if both names are in the array, or get the objects with this names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty roundabout way to zero in on the logic you're trying to express.  Note how the result in `hasMatch` is never even used.  That's really all you're looking for, does the array "have the values".

There's no need to push values to another array and check if *that array* has values.  Just check of the original array has them.

Which could be as simple as:

```js
let result = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

if (result.filter(r => r.name === "FGH" || r.name === "ABC").length === 2) {
  // do logic
}
```

Or if you want to refactor the condition into a variable:

```js
let result = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

let hasMatch = result.filter(r => r.name === "FGH" || r.name === "ABC").length === 2;

if (hasMatch) {
  // do logic
}
```

Or a bit more verbose for clarity:

```js
let result = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

let filteredResult = result.filter(r => r.name === "FGH" || r.name === "ABC");

let hasMatch = filteredResult.length === 2;

if (hasMatch) {
  // do logic
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not optimized for speed, but does the job

```js
let arr = [

  {
    "name": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "name": "CDE"
  },
  {
    "name": "FGH"
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ"
  }
];

let users = ["ABC", "XYZ"]

let hasAllUsers = users.every(user => arr.some(item => item.name == user))

console.log(hasAllUsers)

// if(hasAllUser) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create another array with the **valid** users and filter your array to match each items that are this array.

This can be done using the [Array#includes method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const users = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

const validUsers = ["ABC", "FGH", "AnotherUser"];

const matchUsers = users.filter(user => validUsers.includes(user.name))
console.log(matchUsers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could count the wanted names.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "ABC" }, { name: "CDE" }, { name: "FGH" }, { name: "XYZ" }],
    names = ['ABC', 'FGH'],
    result = data.reduce((t, { name }) => t + names.includes(name), 0);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a named function and pass in the array, key, and one or more values with the rest operator `...values`. Use `.flatMap()` to filter with

```js
[...values].includes(obj[key])
// ["ABC", "XYZ"].includes(obj.name)
```

and any non-match returns an empty array `[]`. The final return is an array with a sub-array and the length of said sub-array.

```js
const result = [["ABC", "XYZ"], 2]
// result[0][0] = "ABC"
// result[0][1] = "XYZ"
// result[1] = 2
```

```js
const arr = [{"name": "ABC"},{"name": "CDE"},{"name": "FGH"},{"name": "XYZ"}];

function hasMatch(array, key, ...values) {
  const result = array.flatMap((obj, idx) =>  
    [...values].includes(obj[key]) ? obj : []);
  return [result, result.length];
}

console.log(hasMatch(arr, "name", "ABC", "XYZ"));
console.log(hasMatch(arr, "name", "FGH", "IJK", "LMN", "ABC", "XYZ"));
```